# compare column of one row with same column of other row and then if there is match update the third column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 1 Million records in my table. 
I want to compare one field called "name" for 1st row to same field of other row and in case of match update a column "parent" with that name . How do i do..?

Example :

```
Name    code    area    Parent
------------------------------------
Nokia   610 cube    
Investments 240 ahnc    
Investments 241 hnnc    
apple   500 sumo    
Iphone  210 robert
```

so when Name = Name , then update Parent with that name

in this case :

```
Name    code    area    Parent
------------------------------------
Nokia   610 cube    
Investments 240 ahnc    Investments
Investments 241 hnnc    Investments
apple   500 sumo    
Iphone  210 robert
```

Comment: is there a row-id to prevent to select the same row. can you post the structure

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 0):

This it not the best solution, but it works:

```
UPDATE table1 SET 'Parent'='Name'
WHERE 'name' IN (
SELECT t1.'Name' FROM table1 t1 HAVING count(*) > 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 set parent = Name where Name in 
  (select Name from 
    (select Name from t1 group by Name having count(Name) > 1) 
  as Name);
```

The double select in subquery is to avoid "Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause" error.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/323f1f/1/0)